# Why jasmine-node doesn't find my spec files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I have installed jasmine-node using npm. My project's directory structure are following:

```
|-lib\
   |-taxCalc.js
|-spec\
   |-taxCalc.spec.coffee
   |-taxCalc.spec.js
|-src\
   |-taxCalc.coffee
```

When I run jasmine-node from root folder with following command (for CoffeeScript):

```
jasmine-node --coffee --verbose spec

Finished in 0.015 seconds
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures
```

Same if I run JavaScript version.

If I explicitly point to spec file tests run fine:

```
jasmine-node --coffee --verbose spec/taxCalc.spec.coffee

Tax calculation
  calculates tax

Finished in 0.009 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures
```

Documentation says that file names should end with 'spec.js' or 'spec.coffee', so everything seems ok.

P.S. I am running on Windows 7.

Comment: the only thing I know is that windows needs paths in node.js to be handled differently. Exmpl; "C:/bla" would need to be "C:\/bla". could be that the dev of jasmine isnt testing on windows..

Comment: Thanks for idea - I'll try to test RegEx used in jasmine-node if it finds windows specific paths.

Comment: I've got a project in Windows with a structure similar to yours but I'm not running into your issue. Does it make a difference if you're more explicit that spec is a directory: ```jasmine-node --coffee --verbose .\spec\```?

Comment: No, even more explicit version didn't help. I tested RegEx used in jasmine-node and it is fine.

Comment: Just found that jasmine-node uses findit to search for files in directory tree and somehow synchronous version of findit doesn't work. It returns only first file in directory (I have hidden VIM's swp file as first). Same time tried callback version and it works fine. Digging deeper :)

Comment: It seems as known issue of findit https://github.com/substack/node-findit/issues/5

Comment: It looks like there's a general issue with path.exists and path.existsSync in node: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2635 After upgrading to node 0.6.9 on Windows 7 ```cake``` can't find my Cakefile. I traced it back and it's running into this node bug. Your jasmine-node issue might be related.

Comment: Dude, ditch Jasmine. I use to use Jasmine, that is until Mocha came along.

Comment: It's good that you've found a workaround. I wanted to mention that the path.exists issue in node on Windows is now resolved in node 0.6.10. The change they did for that may have also fixed findit's issue.

Comment: I had to +1 @JPRichardson - not terribly helpful for those stuck on jasmine but I was having issues on windows, switched to mocha and no problems at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled upon the same problem and have read MarisKs link too late :/ - but came to the same conclusion as described in the issue:
At least on Windows 7, file.stat.ino returns always 0, so the function createInodeChecker() in findit/index.js returns always true and the file will be skipped.

Easiest on-the-fly-fix: edit createInodeChecker to

```
function createInodeChecker() {
    var inodes = {};
    return function inodeSeen(inode) {
        if (inode == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (inodes[inode]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            inodes[inode] = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Not nice, but you can work with it.

Comment: Tested it. It works fine! I also suggested your solution for "findit": https://github.com/substack/node-findit/issues/5

Answer (score 3):

Jasmine-node has been updated in the last week to use walkdir instead of findit which now makes it function in windows. Re-run `npm install jasmine-node` for the update.